# Render compiled template to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's my template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="validationErrors.html">
    <div id="validationErrors">
            <div id="errorListContainer">
                <h2>Your order contains invalid fields:</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="error in validationErrors">{{error.message}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here's my code:

```
var errors = [...];
var template = $templateCache.get("validationErrors.html");
var link = $compile($.trim(template));
var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
scope.validationErrors = errors;
var linked = link(scope);
alert(/* what goes here? */);
scope.$destroy();
```

In the above snippet, how do I render my linked element to a string such that the ng-repeat directive renders out the list of errors?

If I do this...

```
linked.html();
```

... then I get the following even though there are validation errors...

```
<DIV id=errorListContainer>\r\n<H2>Your order contains invalid fields:</H2>\r\n<UL><!-- ngRepeat: error in validationErrors --></UL></DIV>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this...

```
scope.$apply()
alert(linked.html());
```

Comment: `$timeout(function() { alert(linked.prop("outerHTML"));  })` worked better for me (can be called from  within a current digest cycle without error and also  takes the full contents of the html where as html() strips the uppermost parent.